# How to fetch data from MySQL to React html table

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, database, electron

Is there a way to get data from the MySQL database (this can be done whit the Node.js back-end), but I can not create a table from that data in React.js?

Is there a good option to do that?

(I'm creating an electron application whit react and I want to list all the users from the MySQL database)
In PHP is like this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

```
var mysql = window.require('mysql');

function Test() {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'root',
        port : 8889,
        database : 'loginsystem'
    });

    connection.connect();
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
        if (!results.length){
          console.log("error_fetching_data_from_database --",results.length);
        }else{
            console.log(result)
        }
      });

    const listof = (
        //I want print out useres here like table from the database
    )

 return(listof)
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: could you please explain more ? did you prepare a rest api with node js ?

Comment: I'm using **var MySQL = window. require('MySQL);** to connect to MySQL that's working fine and. if I'm just printing out the data from MySQL like on this website (https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp) whit console.log that is working fine too but I want to print out the results not only in the con. connect function but outside the function too like that table in the console but in Html whit react. I posted the code.

Comment: In PHP is this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp but I need to create it in electron whit react and node.js

Comment: Try my answer below

Comment: I don't think it worked to me. Can you send over GitHub the files?

Comment: Your test function it doesn't look like a react component for this reason i thaught it's a node js file

Comment: I can't help you a lot without seeing all project it's too complicated like that